# Como agrupo valores referenciados y los sumo, con mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, npm

Mi objetivo final es que la base de datos me devuelva por ej, los 15 con mas votos type 3. los 15 es cuestion de .limit(15) pero que me devuelva ordenado por cual tiene mas votes type 3 es donde se me complica.

EDIT: la siguiente query, me trae los posts y me hace populate solo en los que tienen type 1. solo me faltaria ordenarlos por los posts que mas elementos tienen en el array votes de ese resultado.

```
models.post.find().populate({path: 'votes', match: {type: 1 }})
```

Tengo un schema de Post al cual se le puede hacer 3 tipos de votos, por ej "no me gusta", "me gusta", "me da igual"

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  votes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Votes' }],
});
```

Entonces plantee el Schema de voto asi, guarda referencia al post y almacena el type (1 = "no me gusta", 2 = "me gusta" y 3 = "me da igual"), el cual ya no me convence si me quieren sugerir un cambio en vez, de solo plantearme la query correcta.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
  type: Number
});
```

entonces cree el endpoint para votar

```
router.post('/vota', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.type > 3 || req.body.type < 1) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "404 oops something bad happened with that vote" });
    }

    let vote = new models.votes(req.body);
    return vote.save().then(result => {
        models.post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.post, { $push: { votes: result.id }})
        .then(
            res.status(200).send(result)
        ).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({ error: err });
        })
    })
});
```

entonces yo necesito ahora crear un endpoint que atreves de query ?type=3 por ej. me traiga todos los post con votos  type 3 ordenados por cual tiene mas.

Comment: creo que no es muy difícil, pues tendrías que filtrar los votos por su tipo `models.post.find({type: 3})` y luego ordenas

Comment: podría llegar a haber muchos miles de post como para hacer eso con logica. es un trabajo para la base de datos. ademas tambien tengo la necesidad de limitar el resultado a 15

Comment: hace tiempo no trabajaba con mongoose y mongodb, te voy a dar un ejemplo, si te sirve pues bien, de lo contrario me avisas y tratare de mejorarlo

Answer (score 0):

Bueno una forma de hacerlo es filtrar los documentos y establecer un limite , como dijiste de 15 documentos y ordenamos de forma ascendente indicándole el campo y la forma (1: ascendente, -1:desendente), para eso usamos la siguiente consulta

```js
resultado = models.post.find({type:3}).sort({type:1}).limit(15);

//iteramos en los resultados
while (resultado .hasNext()) {
 printjson(resultado .next());
}
```

Comment: pero de esta forma nos salteamos lo mas importante, que me traiga todos los post con votos type 3 ordenados por cual tiene mas.

osea que la base de datos me devuelva los 15 mas votados, entonces luego puedo hacer .skip(15).limit(15) para acceder a la segunda pagina, .skip(30), etc

Comment: listo edite la respuesta

Comment: Te falta un punto (.) antes de `sort`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias, ya lo agregue

Comment: pero ahi estas filtando por type: 3 los posts. type: 3 es dentro del voto y y el post solo guarda referencia. Entonces deberia hacer un populate de los votes filtrandolos por type: 3 y ahi buscar que posts tiene mas resultados. por eso digo que a lo mejor deberia cambiar la forma en la que guardo los posts

Comment: hice un edit en el post

Comment: @bartimeoxz lo siento aun estoy investigando mas, ya que gracias a una charla con Maurcio me di cuenta que no estoy ni cerca en hacer lo que pides, tu intento es bueno, pero igual estas lejos, a mas tardar hare la repuesta el dia de mañana

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaria mejor el aggregate framework de Mongo...

Con ese fácilmente puedes filtrar los de tipo 3 y traer solo lo que te interesa.

(No lo he probado... pero debería funcionarte algo similar a esto)

```
models.post.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "votes", //El nombre de tu coleccion de votos
        as: "vote3Count", //Como quieres que se llame el nuevo campo que contenga los documentos
        let: { "id": "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            { 
                $match: { 
                    $expr: { 
                        $and: [ //Filtras solo los de tipo=3, y los que tengan el id = al id del documento post
                            { $eq: [ '$type', 3 ] } ,
                            { $eq: [ '$post', "$$id" ] } 
                        ]
                    } 
                },
            },
            { $count: "count" } //Solo los cuentas
        ]
    }
},
{
    $project: { //Sacas los datos que necesites del post, aqui solo extraigo el id y el vote3Count del pipeline de arriba
        _id: "$_id",
        content: "$_content",
        createdAt: "$createdAt",
        votes3Count: { $ifNull: [ { $arrayElemAt: ['$vote3Count.count', 0] }, 0] }
    }
},
{
    $sort: { votes3Count: -1} //Ordeno por el campo vote3 count
},
{
    $limit: 15 //Limito a 15 resultados
}
])
```

Asi obtienes los primeros 15 posts, ordenados por el que mas votos type=3 tenga de mayor a menor